# cpu_usage() from python psutil library showing 100% of cpu usage, but HWMonitor only 10-11%?

Tags: python, cpu-usage, psutil

Like above, why function cpu_usage shows 100% of cpu, while in HWMonitor or in Windows Task Manager I can see only 10-11% of usage. I got some code that measuring cpu and ram usage. Memory usage seems to be working like charm, but this cpu is somehow 10x greater than in task manager. Why?

```
import random
import threading
import psutil

def display_cpu():
    global running

    running = True

    currentProcess = psutil.Process()

    # start loop
    while running:
        print("CPU: ",currentProcess.cpu_percent(interval=1), "%", "| Memory: ", currentProcess.memory_info().rss/(1024*1024), "MB")

def start():
    global t

    # create thread and start it
    t = threading.Thread(target=display_cpu)
    t.start()

def stop():
    global running
    global t

    # use `running` to stop loop in thread so thread will end
    running = False

    # wait for thread's end
    t.join()

# ---

def insertion_sort():
    nums = []
    for i in range(30000):
        nums.append(random.randint(1, 10000))
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        item_to_insert = nums[i]

        j = i - 1

        while j >= 0 and nums[j] > item_to_insert:
            nums[j + 1] = nums[j]
            j -= 1

        nums[j + 1] = item_to_insert


# ---
for i in range(1):
    start()
    try:
        result = insertion_sort()
    finally:
        stop()
```

Comment: Do you happen to have 8 cores on your CPU? (alternately, 4 with hyperthreading enabled). If so, one core is around 12% (1/8) of the total CPU capacity, but if Python considers one core fully loaded 100% (that is, 8 cores fully loaded = 800%) it would make sense.

Comment: Well, I got Ryzen 1600, so its 6 cores/12 threads cpu

Comment: Hi! what do you intend to measure? because you are measuring your process CPU usage and, since you are inside a never-ending and never-sleeping while loop, the usage is 100%. If you want to measure your overall CPU usage of your whole computer, use `psutil.cpu_percent()`

Comment: I want to measure cpu usage during sorting data by insertion sort algorithm. How much percentange is changing during this proccess, that's all

Comment: Ok. In such a case, divide the process CPU usage between the number of CPUs you have, using: `print("CPU: ",currentProcess.cpu_percent(interval=1) / psutil.cpu_count(), "%", "| Memory: ", currentProcess.memory_info().rss/(1024*1024), "MB")`

Comment: Thank you Kalma for help :)

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject, but having a program benchmark itself seems like the kind of think which could lead to some issues.